# What is a good way to find new western friends in a foreign city?

Tags: philippines, socializing

I moved to Cebu around a month ago. I'm working from home as a computer programmer. I've been living abroad and travelling for a year now.

I'm regularly meeting women and people from the local culture, but sometimes I miss having male friends and people with my own cultural background.

Especially as living in some countries is a culture shock, it's nice to talk again with people with a western cultural background.
I'm a great fan of www.meetup.com, but unfortunately there are not many people in Cebu using it.

What are other good tips to find like-minded people while travelling?

Comment: Have you tried restaurants that serve your home country's food?

Comment: Do you want to meet expats or travellers? For expats there is very often a Facebook Groups. For example, for Georgia it's called "Georgian Wanderers" and for Vientiane, Laos it's called "Vientiane Social". There's likely to be either a Cebu one or a Philippines one which has a number of members/users in Cebu. For travellers staying in a hostel from time to time, or just dropping in for drinks at hostels that have bars. For expats there are expat bars, often with owners from various western countries.

Answer (score 11):

There is no one solution for this. Some suggestions...

- Irish pubs.
- Quiz nights.
- Walking tours.
- Hash House Harriers.
- Toastmasters.
- Internations.
- Critical Mass.

@Taladris' answer made me realise there are more:

- Alliance Française.
- Goethe Institut.
- British Council.

Here are two more that I often check for:

- Gallery openings.
- Facebook events (with an international focus).

Comment: "'Cause wherever in the world you go, you'll find an Irish pub..."

Answer (score 11):

Virtually any country or city with a foreign community also has an **expat forum** online, and these often organize social get-togethers.  I'm not familiar with the Philippines expat scene, but googling "philippines expats forum" returns a whole slew of results, and there's at least one forum dedicated for just Cebu as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what has worked for me in South Korea. Pretty sure that most of this applies also to Cebu.

For example,

1. You can try to use social networks. There are certainly expat groups on Facebook. Search *Expats in Cebu* or *Foreigners in Cebu*. You can also search for more specialized groups such as *French in Cebu*, *Expat Mums in Cebu*, *Hiking in Cebu*...
2. Meetup is an application that is used to organized events, in particular, social gatherings. You can join such a gathering to meet locals and foreigners.
3. Groups on Couch Surfing organize events for travelers, expats and locals.
4. You can also "hijack" some applications to fit your needs. For example, you can use language exchange applications (e.g. HelloTalk) in your own language to meet people from your country. This does not always work since they may think you are wasting their time. You can also use this to meet locals that are interested in your mother tongue; they may know some of your compatriots leaving in town and/or have stayed in your country and know your culture.
5. there are certainly bars whose patrons are mostly foreigners. They usually have Facebook pages in English and organize events like concerts, trivia nights, tacos tuesdays, Halloween parties, Saint Patrick days,...
6. Embassies and cultural centers organize events regularly. The French cultural center of my city have parties with wine and cheese that attract fellow Frenchies from far away.
7. Look for churches/mosques/Jedi temples that have English services.